# Android Intent-Filter Issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an intent-filter as shown below;

[image: intent-filter]

It works on emulator, but on real device it works in facebook app (i dont test other apps), but not on browser.

Any help would perfect!

Thx a lot

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "but not on browser" means. What **specifically** did you do and what **specifically** were the results?

Comment: I trying open "http://example.com" on my phone's browser (chrome), my application should open but its not. When I click a link that goes to "http://example.com" on facebook app, my application opens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many browsers, including Chrome and Firefox, do not pay attention to activities with these filters. If they see an `http` or `https` URL, they process it themselves, just loading the Web page.

These `<intent-filter>` structures are designed for links from other apps, such as those embedded in tweets, text messages, Facebook posts, and the like.

Comment: Example, when i search a tweet from chrome, it opens twitter application. How can i do something like that.

Ps: on Android's native browser, intent-filter works!

Comment: @Hyperion: It is possible that they are using their custom `twitter` scheme. "on Android's native browser, intent-filter works!" -- except that browser is not installed on Android 4.4+ devices, which make up half of the Android ecosystem at the moment.

Comment: How twitter scheme shown on google search ? Can I do something like that for my app ?

Comment: @Hyperion: "How twitter scheme shown on google search ?" -- sorry, I thought that you meant searching within the Twitter site.

Comment: No, I open chrome, search something and when i click a tweet, it opens in twitter app. (Link looks like "https://twitter.com/....")

Comment: @Hyperion: Then I have no idea how Twitter is doing that, other than perhaps a special relationship with Google. I examined their manifest and did not see anything unusual that would explain why it works for them and does not work for us. You might try repeating the test using Firefox.